# Guice - accessing original value from within override

Tags: java, guice

In a **test** I'd like to **wrap** an object that is already provided by a different module.
Essentially something like this (but working):

```
Guice.createInjector(Modules.override(
    // This module lives somewhere else and I rather can't change it
    new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
          bind(Ticker.class).to(TickerImpl.class);
        }

        @Provides @Singleton
        public Tacker getTacker(Ticker ticker) {
          return new Tacker(ticker);
        }
    }).with(new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
        }

        // This doesn't work. oldTicker is an instance of 
        // DelegatingInvocationHandler that references the
        // result of this function causing infinite recursion.
        @Provides @Singleton Ticker getTicker(Ticker oldTicker) {
          return new SpyingTicker(oldTicker);
        }
    })).getInstance(Tacker.class).tack();
```

Is there a way of doing this? The only solution that I found was to do this instead in the overwrite:

```
        @Provides @Singleton
        public Tacker getTacker(Ticker ticker) {
          return new Tacker(new SpyingTicker(ticker));
        }
```

which is not ideal since it duplicates the logic of the original module and doesn't replace the injection of the "Ticker" everywhere (just in the creation of the "Tacker")

Comment: Is this an integration test or a unit test?

Comment: It's an integration test. I want to count the number of times some method of a real object is being called. So I'm wrapping it in a proxy but I need to be able to inject the proxy and proxy needs to be able to call the original object.

Comment: The module you are trying to wrap... you can't change it EVER? Or you can't change it often?

Comment: It's part of another team's project. Theoretically if I have a very good reason for it I could change it but I was hoping that there's less intrusive way of solving this IMO rather generic problem. It's not the first time I have a need for something like this in a test. I think the other team would frown upon complicating their code just so mine few lvls up the stack could write a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a test, the best solution is to simply replace the entire module provided by the other team. This allows you to change bindings however you see fit. However, I can understand why you would not want to do that if there is only one change.

If you can get the other team to make a small change, I might try the following:

```
public class ProductionModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        // snip
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    protected MyObject provideMyObject(Dependency dependency) {
        return delegateProvide(dependency);
    }

    // note the lack of annotations
    protected MyObject delegateProvide(Dependency dependency) {
        return new MyObject(dependency);
    }
}
```

Then, in your test:

```
public class TestModule extends ProductionModule {
   @Override
   protected MyObject delegateProvide(Dependency dependency) {
       return new MyObjectSpy(super.delegateProvide(dependency));
   }
}
```